# How do I make a jQuery click event revert to what it otherwise would've been?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

I have a `click` event

```
        $('[data-assetid]').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url : '/somemethod',
                method : 'POST',
                data : { pageid : $('input[name="pageid"]').val() },
                success : function ( retobj ) {
                    // ... 
                }
            });
            
        });
```

that is on elements that by default have click events (`<img>`s, `<a>`s, etc.). What I want it to do at the end of the `success` callback is remove the click event I had attached in the first place, so that it falls back to what it otherwise would've been. How do I do this?

Comment: Check the las example of the [jQuery.unbidn() docs](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/). This should be what you are looking for. [jQuery.bidn() docs](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) might be useful too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `jQuery.one` ([check API)](http://api.jquery.com/one/); it will bind it once and then unbind after the first call.

Like this:

```
    $('[data-assetid]').one("click", function(){
        $.ajax({
            url : '/somemethod',
            method : 'POST',
            data : { pageid : $('input[name="pageid"]').val() },
            success : function ( retobj ) {
                // ... 
            }
        });

    });
```